# Quick SQL group by question

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with 2 columns number and name.

```
number  name 
--------------
0       name1
3       name4
3       name2
5       name1
```

So the number column has repeats in it and one or more (distinct) names assigned to each number. But for example, number 3 could have the same name as number 5.

How do I show all the distinct names for each number using group by in such a way that I get as a result both number and name.

I am trying to do this but I can't figure it due to must having the columns in SELECT in GROUP BY also.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is for OMGPonies...

Comment: Can you show what your desired output would be? That might be easier to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT NUMBER, NAME
  FROM TABLENAME
    GROUP BY NUMBER, NAME
    ORDER BY NUMBER
```

Comment: In a way, I want to group everything by Number. So I want to get the DISTINCT number and for each number I want to get all the names that correspond with that number.

Comment: Not sure if could do that, unless you meant that you wanted apply an order? Also, what if you have the number 3 two times with different names?- you will have to show the result twice: one for (3, name1) and one for (3, name2)

Comment: I think I lose myself in the thoughts. You are right. I can just order it.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing 'Number' is a reserved word in sql so don't use it as a column name

Suppose your 'Number' column name is 'Number1"

then try this

select name, number1 from tableName
GROUP BY name, number1